# docker-compose fails to recognize when images are rebuilt sometimes ... often same code is OK

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-in-docker

I have a devops container inside of which I execute `docker build` and `docker-compose up` commands which run OK then (on same server or different server with same code) sometimes incorrectly fail to `Recreate` sibling containers after their images are rebuilt.

My process successfully rebuilds a pair of two underlying docker images however

```
docker-compose up
```

sometimes fails to pickup that change and incorrectly says up-to-date on freshly rebuilt images when it should be saying Recreating

I am executing identical code across several servers each with varying OS ( ubuntu 16.04 or debian 8 or debian 9) and varying docker versions ( either  18.04.0-ce-rc1  or  18.03.0-ce ) ... am currently working to track down root cause however see good and bad behavior across each of above OS and docker versions

This issue does not seem related to https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3574

Yes I am tagging the images and doing a push to local docker repository

```
docker build --tag localhost:5000/hygge/loudweb-admin .
```

docker push to my local docker repository is

```
docker push localhost:5000/hygge/loudweb-admin
```

it also does similar to above image loudweb-enduser

here my my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:

nodejs-admin:
  image: ${GKE_APP_REPO_PREFIX}/${PROJECT_ID}/loudweb-admin
  container_name: loud_admin
  restart: always
  depends_on:
    - loudmongo
    - loudmail
  volumes:
    - /cryptdata4/var/log/loudlog-admin:/loudlog-admin
    - /cryptdata5/var/log/blobs:/blobs
    - /cryptdata5/var:/cryptdata5/var
    - /cryptdata5/var/tools:/tools
    - /cryptdata6/var/log/loudlog-enduser:/loudlog-enduser
    - $SOURCE_REPO_DIR/tests:/tmp/tests
    - ${TMPDIR_GRAND_PARENT}/curr/loud-build/${PROJECT_ID}/webapp/admin/bundle:/tmp
  environment:
    - MONGO_SERVICE_HOST=loudmongo
    - MONGO_SERVICE_PORT=$GKE_MONGO_PORT 
    - MONGO_URL=mongodb://loudmongo:$GKE_MONGO_PORT/test
    - METEOR_SETTINGS=${METEOR_SETTINGS}
    - MAIL_URL=smtp://support@${GKE_DOMAIN_NAME}:blah@loudmail:587/
    - GKE_NOTIF_TASK_OVERDUE=$GKE_NOTIF_TASK_OVERDUE
    - GKE_NOTIF_TASK_PUSH=$GKE_NOTIF_TASK_PUSH
    - GKE_NOTIF_PLANS_RECUR=$GKE_NOTIF_PLANS_RECUR
  links:
    - loudmongo
    - loudmail
  ports:
   - 127.0.0.1:3001:3001
  working_dir: /tmp
  command: /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

nodejs-enduser:
  image: ${GKE_APP_REPO_PREFIX}/${PROJECT_ID}/loudweb-enduser
  container_name: loud_enduser
  restart: always
  depends_on:
    - nodejs-admin
    - loudmongo
    - loudmail
  volumes:
    - /cryptdata6/var/log/loudlog-enduser:/loudlog-enduser
    - /cryptdata5/var/log/blobs:/blobs
    - ${TMPDIR_GRAND_PARENT}/curr/loud-build/${PROJECT_ID}/webapp/enduser/bundle:/tmp
    - ${TMPDIR_GRAND_PARENT}/curr/loud-build/${PROJECT_ID}/webapp/admin/bundle/programs/server/assets/app/config/apn-cert.pem:/private/config/apn-cert.pem
    - ${TMPDIR_GRAND_PARENT}/curr/loud-build/${PROJECT_ID}/webapp/admin/bundle/programs/server/assets/app/config/apn-key.pem:/private/config/apn-key.pem
  environment:
    - MONGO_SERVICE_HOST=loudmongo
    - MONGO_SERVICE_PORT=$GKE_MONGO_PORT 
    - MONGO_URL=mongodb://loudmongo:$GKE_MONGO_PORT/test
    - METEOR_SETTINGS=${METEOR_SETTINGS}
    - MAIL_URL=smtp://support@${GKE_DOMAIN_NAME}:puMDcxNmEwMDU5MmJjZjNiNzQ3M2ZlNTJjNDYyOGI1NTggIC0Ksy@loudmail:587/
  links:
    - loudmongo
    - loudmail
  ports:
   - 127.0.0.1:3000:3000
  working_dir: /tmp
  command: /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

loudmongo:
  image: mongo
  container_name: loud_mongo
  restart: always
  ports:
   - 127.0.0.1:$GKE_MONGO_PORT:$GKE_MONGO_PORT
  volumes:
   - /cryptdata7/var/data/db:/data/db

loudmail:
  image: ${GKE_APP_REPO_PREFIX}/${PROJECT_ID}/loudmail
  hostname: mail
  domainname: ${GKE_DOMAIN_NAME}
  container_name: loud_mail
  restart: always
  environment:
    - DMS_DEBUG=1
    - ENABLE_MANAGESIEVE=1
    - ENABLE_FAIL2BAN=1
    - SA_TAG=2.0
    - SA_TAG2=6.31
    - SA_KILL=6.31
    - SSL_TYPE=letsencrypt
  ports:
    - 127.0.0.1:25:25
    - 127.0.0.1:110:110
    - 127.0.0.1:143:143
    - 127.0.0.1:587:587
    - 127.0.0.1:993:993
    - 127.0.0.1:995:995
    - 127.0.0.1:4190:4190


loud-devops:
  image: dind
  container_name: loud_devops
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 127.0.0.1:9000:9000
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock   
    - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker   
    - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7  
    - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpm.so.2:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpm.so.2
    - /home/asya/src/github.com/blahblah:/inner_home/asya/src/github.com/blahblah 
    - /home/asya/.docker:/inner_home/asya/.docker
    - /cryptdata5/var/tools/inner_home/asya:/inner_home/asya
    - $GKE_DIND_SUPERVISOR_LOG_DIR:/var/log/supervisor
    - /cryptdata5/var/tools/usr/local/go:/usr/local/go
    - /cryptdata6/var/log/tmp/asya01:/cryptdata6/var/log/tmp/asya01
    - /cryptdata6/var/log/tmp/shared:/cryptdata6/var/log/tmp/shared
    - /cryptdata5/var/tools/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin 
    - /cryptdata:/cryptdata
    - /cryptdata4:/cryptdata4
    - /cryptdata5:/cryptdata5
    - /cryptdata6:/cryptdata6
    - /cryptdata7:/cryptdata7
    - /etc/letsencrypt/live:/etc/letsencrypt/live
    - /usr/local/ssl:/usr/local/ssl
    - /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker
  command: /usr/bin/supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

The bottom most container in above ( loud-devops ) contains a webhook daemon which listens for a git push to trigger a rebuild cycle. While inside that container the system issues all my docker command including docker build create fresh images for two containers ( nodejs-admin and nodejs-enduser ) then while inside the container I issue the

```
docker-compose -f /docker-compose.yaml up -d
```

which then sometimes incorrectly displays

```
loud_devops is up-to-date
loud_mongo is up-to-date
loud_mail is up-to-date
loud_admin is up-to-date
loud_enduser is up-to-date
```

other times it incorrectly displays

```
docker-compose -f /docker-compose.yml up -d
Recreating loud_devops ...
Recreating loud_mongo ...
Recreating loud_mail ...
```

which should NEVER happen since those 3 images are never rebuilt ... to me that scenario is a blatant docker logic bug ...

whereas other times works OK and correctly displays

```
loud_mongo is up-to-date
loud_mail is up-to-date
loud_devops is up-to-date
Recreating loud_admin ... done
Recreating loud_enduser ... done
```

On the host of each server I have docker installed then as you can see in above yaml for container loud-devops  I mount as volumes various docker dirs to enable the execution of docker in docker from inside container loud-devops

A critical piece of evidence :  on a server which has finished its rebuild cycle where it successfully rebuilt both images loudweb-enduser and loudweb-admin  then incorrectly shows

```
docker-compose -f /docker-compose.yml up -d 
loud_mail is up-to-date
loud_mongo is up-to-date
loud_devops is up-to-date
loud_admin is up-to-date
loud_enduser is up-to-date
```

where the `docker-compose up` command gets executed by the system while inside container  loud-devops ... IF I then manually login to that same server then manually issue the same command it works correctly :

```
docker-compose -f /docker-compose.yml up -d 
loud_devops is up-to-date
loud_mail is up-to-date
loud_mongo is up-to-date
Recreating loud_admin ... done
Recreating loud_enduser ... done
```

Comment: Do you tag the built images? this might happen if you build & tag an image with the tag which already exists = rewrite the previous version, then when you do docker-compose up it won't recreate because the version is the same. I would like to know if --force-rebuild and/or --always-recreate-deps solves the issue and I would also like to see the docker-compose file, I might be able to advice further afterwards

Comment: @TomášTibenský  to respond to your questions - the rebuild logic is outside the docker-compose.yaml so I have never used nor believe I can use --force-rebuild or --always-recreate-deps

Comment: what about running docker-compose -f /docker-compose.yml pull and then docker-compose -f /docker-compose.yml up -d ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to put a docker pull into my launch script ... as in

```
docker-compose -f ${GKE_COMPOSE_YAML} pull
```

just before issuing

```
docker-compose -f ${GKE_COMPOSE_YAML} up -d
```

which seems strange since most of the time it works OK without issuing pull ... I am using a local docker registry